# Why do I keep getting a black screen after running this code?

Tags: pygame, displayobject, python-3.11

Can somebody please teach me how to create a chessboard in Python properly. I have tried different sizes, different images but I keep getting a black screen as soon as I run the code. Your help will higly be appreciated! Here's the code.
Chess pieces set can be downloaded here commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:PNG_chess_pieces/Standard_transparent

```
import pygame
import sys

SQUARE_SIZE = 80
BOARD_SIZE = SQUARE_SIZE * 8
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

pygame.init()
WINDOW_SIZE = (600, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)





# Define the starting position of the pieces
START_POSITION = [
    ["br", "bn", "bb", "bq", "bk", "bb", "bn", "br"],
    ["bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp"],
    [" ", ".", " ", ".", " ", ".", " ", "."],
    [".", " ", ".", " ", ".", " ", ".", " "],
    [" ", ".", " ", ".", " ", ".", " ", "."],
    [".", " ", ".", " ", ".", " ", ".", " "],
    ["wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp"],
    ["wr", "wn", "wb", "wq", "wk", "wb", "wn", "wr"]
]


class ChessPiece:
    """
    A class to represent a chess piece.

    Attributes:
        color (str): The color of the piece ('w' for white, 'b' for black).
        piece_type (str): The type of the piece ('p' for pawn, 'r' for rook, 'n' for knight,
            'b' for bishop, 'q' for queen, 'k' for king).
        image (pygame.Surface): The image of the piece.
    """

    def __init__(self, color, piece_type, image):
        """
        Initialize the ChessPiece object.

        Args:
            color (str): The color of the piece ('w' for white, 'b' for black).
            piece_type (str): The type of the piece ('p' for pawn, 'r' for rook, 'n' for knight,
                'b' for bishop, 'q' for queen, 'k' for king).
            image (pygame.Surface): The image of the piece.
        """
        self.color = color
        self.piece_type = piece_type
        self.image = image

    def __repr__(self):
        """
        Return a string representation of the ChessPiece object.

        Returns:
            str: A string representation of the ChessPiece object.
        """
        return f'{self.color}{self.piece_type}'


class ChessBoard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = START_POSITION
        self.move_history = []
        self.captured_pieces = {'w': [], 'b': []}
        self.white_to_move = True
        self.images = {}
        self.load_images()

    def load_images(self):
        for color in ['w', 'b']:
            for piece in ['p', 'r', 'n', 'b', 'q', 'k']:
                self.images[color + piece] = pygame.image.load(f"pieces/{color}{piece}.png")

    def get_piece(self, row, col):
        piece_code = self.board[row][col]
        if piece_code == ' ' or piece_code == '.':
            return None
        color = piece_code[0]
        piece_type = piece_code[1]
        return ChessPiece(color, piece_type)

    def get_all_moves(self, color):
        moves = []
        for row in range(8):
            for col in range(8):
                piece = self.get_piece(row, col)
                if piece is not None and piece.color == color:
                    piece_moves = piece.get_moves(row, col, self.board)
                    moves.extend(piece_moves)
        return moves

    def make_move(self, move):
        start_row, start_col = move.start_pos
        end_row, end_col = move.end_pos
        start_piece = self.board[start_row][start_col]
        end_piece = self.board[end_row][end_col]
        self.board[start_row][start_col] = ' '
        self.board[end_row][end_col] = start_piece
        self.move_history.append(move)
        if end_piece != ' ':
            color = end_piece[0]
            self.captured_pieces[color].append(end_piece[1])
        self.white_to_move = not self.white_to_move

    def draw(self, screen):
        # Draw the squares on the board
        for row in range(8):
            for col in range(8):
                color = (191, 128, 64) if (row + col) % 2 == 0 else (255, 206, 158)
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(col * 80, row * 80, 80, 80))
        # Draw the pieces on the board
        for row in range(8):
            for col in range(8):
                piece = self.board[row][col]
                if piece != ' ':
                    img = self.images[piece]
                    screen.blit(img, pygame.Rect(col * 80, row * 80, 80, 80))

        # Draw the captured pieces
    def draw_captured_pieces(self, surface):
        white_captured = [piece for piece in self.captured_pieces if piece.isupper()]
        black_captured = [piece for piece in self.captured_pieces if piece.islower()]

        x = y = 0
        for piece in white_captured:
            if x > 7:
                y += 1
                x = 0
            surface.blit(self.piece_images[piece], (x * SQUARE_SIZE + BOARD_SIZE + 10, y * SQUARE_SIZE + 10))
            x += 1

        x = y = 0
        for piece in black_captured:
            if x > 7:
                y += 1
                x = 0
            surface.blit(self.piece_images[piece], (x * SQUARE_SIZE + BOARD_SIZE + 10, y * SQUARE_SIZE + 60))
            x += 1
    
    def draw_board(self):
        for row in range(8):
            for col in range(8):
                color = self.get_square_color(row, col)
                pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, color, pygame.Rect(col*SQUARE_SIZE, row*SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE))
                
                piece = self.board[row][col]
                if piece:
                    image = self.images[piece.get_image_name()]
                    self.screen.blit(image, pygame.Rect(col*SQUARE_SIZE, row*SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE))
    

    def run(self):
        while not self.done:
            self.clock.tick(60)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.done = True

            self.draw_board()
            self.draw_captured_pieces()
            self.draw_move_history()

            pygame.display.flip()

        pygame.quit()



    # Draw the move history
    def draw_move_history(self, surface):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 16)
        x, y = BOARD_SIZE + 10, 200
        for move in self.move_history:
            if move[1] is not None:
                notation = self.get_notation(move)
                text = f"{move[0]}. {notation}"
            else:
                text = move[0]
            text_surface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
            surface.blit(text_surface, (x, y))
            y += text_surface.get_height() + 5

    # Draw the user interface
    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.fill(WHITE)
        self.draw_board(surface)
        self.draw_valid_moves(surface)
        self.draw_pieces(surface)
        self.draw_captured_pieces(surface)
        self.draw_move_history(surface)
        pygame.display.flip()
        
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    
    # Draw the game board, pieces, and other elements here
    
    pygame.display.update()
```

I tried different file extensions, tried to change background colour for the board, I messed around with the square sizes but I kept getting the annoying black screen. I tried different places for the lines

```
# Draw the game board, pieces, and other elements here

pygame.display.update()
```

Somehow I won't get rid of the black screen after running the code.

Comment: Your application loop draws nothing at all. You missed to call `draw()` in the application loop. Also the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) of your code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not continue to the execution flow. You encapsulated the main loop inside the class definition. But the class definition is not executed until you instantiate it.
Add this condition to the end of your code and then put your mainloop there.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        ...
        Your mainloop here
        ....
```

Comment: The mainloop is not executed. So the screen is never drawn. And everything is black.